# external domain controller for multiple LAN merging

Tags: lan, active-directory, merge, windows-domain

my home network consists of two pcs and one laptop all behind one DSL Router. Simple Question:

Is it possible to set up a Windows Domain Controller on a V-Server (hosted in the Internet) in such way that the DC can distinguish my PCs and Laptop (although they have the same external ip address) ?

If so, is it possible to add PCs from my mothers LAN in such way that i can generate a family domain of distributed pcs?

Comment: Just as a web server doesn't need to distinguish between internal clients if you had two computers connecting to the same website, the Domain Controller doesn't need to distinguish between internal clients. Your firewall will do that in it's session/state table.

Comment: so you are saying the TCP Layer will do that for me

Comment: No, I'm saying your firewall will do that for you. Your firewall tracks all sessions and maintains the state of those sessions in it's session/state table. So when client 1 connects to the DC the firewall will "register" that session in it's session/state table. When client 2 connects to the DC that connection is maintained in another entry in the session/state table of the firewall.